# Add alias to the collection targeted in lookup

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am a beginner in MongoDB. I will try my best to explain this as easy as possible, so I will take an internet example of collection, instead of the more complicated schema I am working with!

I have two collections as follows:

**Users:**

```
[
   {
     "_id":{"$oid":"610bcc467b0c4008346547b8"},
     "name":"xyz",
     "email":"xyz@gmail.com",
     "password":"xyz",
     "gender":"MALE"
   }
]
```

**Posts:**

```
[
   {
    "_id": {"$oid":"610bce417b0c4008346547bc"},
    "image":"myImage 1", 
    "caption":"r/Mars",
    "user_id":"610bcc467b0c4008346547b8"
   },
   { 
    "_id": {"$oid":"610bce417b0c4008346547be"},
    "image":"myImage 2", 
    "caption":"hmm",
    "user_id":"610bcc467b0c4008346547b8" 
   },
   { 
    "_id": {"$oid":"610bce417b0c4008346547bd"},
    "image":"myImage 3", 
    "caption":"..",
    "user_id":"610bcc467b0c4008346547b8"
   }
]
```

I want to join these two collections using `$lookup`. So I use the following aggregation on the **users** collection:

```
{
    '$addFields': {
        'userStrId': {
            '$toString': '$_id'
        }
    }
}, {
    '$lookup': {
        'from': 'posts', 
        'localField': 'userStrId', 
        'foreignField': 'user_id', 
        'as': 'user_posts'
    }
},
```

I used `$addFields` to add the `_id` field of the user as a string field, so I can use it in `$lookup`,

The following result is generated:

```
[
   {
     "_id":{"$oid":"610bcc467b0c4008346547b8"},
     "name":"xyz",
     "email":"xyz@gmail.com",
     "password":"xyz",
     "gender":"MALE",
     "user_posts": [
        {
          "_id": {"$oid":"610bce417b0c4008346547bc"},
          "image":"myImage 1", 
          "caption":"r/Mars",
          "user_id":"610bcc467b0c4008346547b8"
        },
        { 
          "_id": {"$oid":"610bce417b0c4008346547be"},
          "image":"myImage 2", 
          "caption":"hmm",
          "user_id":"610bcc467b0c4008346547b8" 
        },
        { 
          "_id": {"$oid":"610bce417b0c4008346547bd"},
          "image":"myImage 3", 
          "caption":"..",
          "user_id":"610bcc467b0c4008346547b8"
        }
     ]
   }
]
```

The question that I have right now is, how can I add a field to each of the documents in the `user_posts` such that I get the following result:

```
[
       {
         "_id":{"$oid":"610bcc467b0c4008346547b8"},
         "name":"xyz",
         "email":"xyz@gmail.com",
         "password":"xyz",
         "gender":"MALE",
         "user_posts": [
            {
              "_id": {"$oid":"610bce417b0c4008346547bc"},
              "image":"myImage 1", 
              "caption":"r/Mars",
              "user_id":"610bcc467b0c4008346547b8",
              "post_id":"610bce417b0c4008346547bc"
            },
            { 
              "_id": {"$oid":"610bce417b0c4008346547be"},
              "image":"myImage 2", 
              "caption":"hmm",
              "user_id":"610bcc467b0c4008346547b8",
              "post_id": "610bce417b0c4008346547be"
            },
            { 
              "_id": {"$oid":"610bce417b0c4008346547bd"},
              "image":"myImage 3", 
              "caption":"..",
              "user_id":"610bcc467b0c4008346547b8",
              "post_id":"610bce417b0c4008346547bd"
            }
         ]
       }
    ]
```

`post_id` added to each of the documents, and its value equal to the `_id` of that document converted to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a stage at the end of your pipeline stages,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `user_posts`
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object of `user_posts` and new fields `user_id` and `post_id`

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      user_posts: {
        $map: {
          input: "$user_posts",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                user_id: "$userStrId",
                post_id: { $toString: "$$this._id" }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NcojdZm1beL)